# Gradle kotlin script, > Plugin with id `kotlin` not found

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried to migrate one of my [project](https://github.com/elect86/kotlin-unsigned) to Gradle using a Kotlin script.

These are my steps:

- substituted the `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` with [this one](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/samples/hello-kotlin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar)
- updated the `distributionUrl` of `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to the same as [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/samples/hello-kotlin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L5)
- created the corresponding [`build.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/elect86/kotlin-unsigned/blob/master/build.gradle.kts)
- setting `settings.gradle` to `rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'`

At that point Intellij detects it and suggests:

> You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources. It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation.

-> Ok, apply suggestion!

> Gradle 'hello-kotlin' project refresh failed
>
> Error:Plugin with id 'kotlin' not found.

Then I also tried to try one of the official [samples](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples/hello-kotlin):

- cloned the repo
- opened the sample
- same error

...what am I doing wrong?

I came back to the official sample, tried to invalidate cache and restart, it didn't work

I tried to remove

```
apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
}
```

Refresh Gradle, add it again, refresh Gradle, it worked

If I open a src file, Intellij says:

> Kotlin not configured

However the sample seems running now..

Intellij 2017.1 EAP

Kotlin 1.1m04

Comment: What version of IDEA kotlin plugin you using?

Comment: 2017.1, build IC-171.2014.21

Comment: Check it in Tool -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates. For working with Kotlin Script Gradle 1.1 version required

Comment: I am using 1.1 m04

Answer (score 1):

It seems working now, this is what I did:

- I closed the project and quitted Intellij
- in the project directory, I removed:

  - `.gradle`
  - `.idea`
  - `build`
  - `gradle`
  - `gradlew`
  - `gradlew.bat`
  - `settings.gradle`
- I left only `src` and the `build.gradle.kts` script
- copy/paste from the `hello-kotlin`:

  - `gradle`
  - `gradlew`
  - `gradlew.bat`
  - `settings.gradle`
- open Intellij, chose "Open Project" and it was automatically showing up as a Gradle Project, selected and opened